# Caught throwable error while accessing lucenesearch index hmc

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using hybris, and I'm stack with an exception while accessing to hmc.

> [de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job] [Cluster 0: Lucenesearch-UpdateIndex-Job::de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.UpdateIndexJob] [ | | | | | | | ] - Caught throwable error while accessing lucenesearch index hmc de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.IndexAccessException: error while accessing lucenesearch index hmc[HY-0] at de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.LuceneIndex.removeItemFromIndexImpl(LuceneIndex.java:878) at de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.LuceneIndex.removeItemFromIndex(LuceneIndex.java:821) at de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.UpdateIndexJob.performCronJob(UpdateIndexJob.java:338) at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1297) at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:815) at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.access$1(Job.java:772) at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job$JobRunable.run(Job.java:677) at de.hybris.platform.util.threadpool.PoolableThread.run(PoolableThread.java:198) Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/hybris/install/data/luceneindex/prod-hmc-en/write.lock at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:702) at de.hybris.platform.lucenesearch.jalo.LuceneIndex.removeItemFromIndexImpl(LuceneIndex.java:845) ... 7 more

Thank you.

Comment: Put some more info, when you are facing this issue

Comment: Is SOLR starting correctly ?

Comment: this problem occur all the time, HMC working fine but I get this exception